# getView() inside Custom ArrayAdapter is not called after onResume()

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter, getview

I'm hopeless about this!
I have tried to find what is happening for 4 days now..

Basically I am fetching all of the songs from my device and show them in a listView.

The listView is located inside a simple fragment called MainFragment.

The fragment is located inside a ViewPager with swipe left-right options.

The listView and it's adapter are working GREAT in the first initial run.

BUT, after my app is going into background and than user brings the app back into front the listView is not being loaded!
Those three lines are located where I initiate the adapter with the listView and ArrayList:

```
            Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List View - " + String.valueOf(songsListView.getCount()));
        Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List Adapter - " + String.valueOf(songListAdapter.getCount()));
        Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List - " + String.valueOf(Constants.songList.size()));
```

They all return the correct number of songs in the device!

But inside the adapter, getView() is not being called at all..
I have tried to clear the adapter' clear the listView, clear the Songs List, clear the entire layout of the entire app! and than reload it in onResume()..
But nothing seems to work :(

MainFragment:

```js
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  public static boolean stopSearch = false;

  public static ListView songsListView;
  public ListView playListListView;
  public PlayListListAdapter playeListAdapter;
  public SongListAdapter songListAdapter;

  public RelativeLayout play_list_container;
  public Button cancelPlayList;
  public Button okPlayList;
  public Button chooseAll;

  private View mRootView;@
  Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_layout, container,
      false);

    Log.w("Main Fragment", "Has been created");
    return mRootView;
  }

  @
  Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public void initLists() {
    try {
      if (songsListView == null) {
        Log.d("Main Fragment", "initListView");
        songsListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
      }

      if (playListListView == null) {
        playListListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.playListListView);
        play_list_container = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_container);
      }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      Log.d("Main Fragment", "initLists " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  public void onResume() {
    try {
      initLists();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      songsListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
      playListListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.playListListView);
      play_list_container = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_container);
    }
    //  
    Log.d("Main Fragment", "startSongsScan");
    SongsHelper.getInstance().startSongsScan();

    setOnClicks();
    super.onResume();
  }

  private void setOnClicks() {
    songsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View arg1, int position, long var4) {
        ((Main) getActivity()).performListViewClick(position);
      }
    });
    songsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {@
      Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View arg1, int position, long var4) {
        final Song song = (Song) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        song.setCanDelete(true);
        songListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
      }
    });
    chooseAll = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.chooseAll);
    chooseAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Main) getActivity()).initPlayListAllSongsSelected();
      }
    });
    okPlayList = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.okPlayList);
    okPlayList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Main) getActivity()).mPlayerUiHelper.savePlayList();
        play_list_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        songsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
    cancelPlayList = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.cancelPlayList);
    cancelPlayList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@
      Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Main) getActivity()).mPlayerUiHelper.cancelPlayList();
        play_list_container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        songsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
  }

  public void setListAdapter() {

    if (songListAdapter == null) {
      songListAdapter = new SongListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.song_row, Constants.songList);
      songsListView.setAdapter(songListAdapter);
    } else {
      songListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    if (songsListView == null || songsListView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
      Log.d("Main Fragment", "Restart Views");
    } else {
      //Songs UI Helper
      Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List View - " + String.valueOf(songsListView.getCount()));
      Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List Adapter - " + String.valueOf(songListAdapter.getCount()));
      Log.d("Main Fragment", "Songs List - " + String.valueOf(Constants.songList.size()));
    }
  }

}
```

SongListAdapter

```js
public class SongListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < Song > {

  Context mContext;
  int mResource;
  List < Song > mSongs;
  private ViewHolder holder;

  public SongListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List < Song > objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource = resource;
    this.mSongs = objects;

    try {
      Comparator cp = Song.getComparator(Song.SortParameter.TITLE_ASCENDING);
      Collections.sort(mSongs, cp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "started");
    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "Songs Count When Started - " + mSongs.size());
  }

  @
  Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Song song = getItem(position);

    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "getView");
    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "Songs Count - " + mSongs.size());
    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "Song - " + song.getTitle());

    if (convertView == null) {
      //create new view
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.songText = (ZenTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
      holder.songArtist = (ZenTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songArtist);
      holder.songPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songIcon);
      convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Set Artist Name
    if (song.getArtist() != null && !song.getArtist().startsWith("<unknown>")) {
      holder.songText.setText(song.getTitle());
      holder.songArtist.setText(song.getArtist());
    } else {
      holder.songText.setText(song.getTitle());
      holder.songArtist.setText(song.getArtist());
    }

    //Set Song image
    setAlbumArt(song);

    //Set item selected
    holder.song_rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_rl);
    if (song.isSelected() == true) {
      holder.song_rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_trans_back_selected);
    } else {
      holder.song_rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_trans_back);
    }

    //Spinning record animation
    if (song.isAnimationActive()) {
      holder.songPhoto.startAnimation(
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate));
    } else {
      holder.songPhoto.clearAnimation();
    }


    //Set item for deletion
    holder.deleteSong = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteFromList);
    if (song.isCanDelete() == true) {
      final int positionSelected = position;
      holder.deleteSong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      holder.deleteSong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @
        Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Main.mPlayerUiHelper.showSpecialToast(mSongs.get(positionSelected).getTitle() + " Has Been Deleted..");
          mSongs.remove(positionSelected);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
          notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
      });
    } else
      holder.deleteSong.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout song_rl;
    ZenTextView songText;
    ZenTextView songArtist;
    ImageView songPhoto;
    ImageView deleteSong;
  }

  private void setAlbumArt(Song song) {
    if (song.getAlbumID() > 0) {
      Uri artUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), song.getAlbumID());
      try {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
          .load(artUri)
          .error(R.drawable.list_image)
          .into(holder.songPhoto);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
          .load(R.drawable.list_image)
          .into(holder.songPhoto);
      }
    }
  }

  @
  Override
  public int getCount() {
    Log.d("Songs Adapter", "getCount() - " + mSongs.size());
    return mSongs.size();
  }
}
```

Main Activity:

```js
 @
 Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

   //For Phone Listening
   Constants.mContext = this;
 }
```

```js
 @
 Override
  protected void onResume() {

   if (Constants.songList == null) {
     Log.d("PlayerUiHelper", "songList was null..");
     Constants.songList = new ArrayList < Song > ();
     Constants.songListSearch = new ArrayList < Song > ();
     Constants.songListShuffle = new ArrayList < Song > ();
   }

   Constants.activityOff = false;
   initStartPlayer();
   super.onResume();
 }
```

```js
 public void initUIfromService() {
   introPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Constants.mContext);

   setViews();
   initMediaControllersOnClicks();
   initTabViews();
   initMoreButton();

   mPlayerUiHelper.setHeaderOnClicks();

   //Start Service
   Intent songIntent = new Intent(Main.this, SongsHelper.class);
   startService(songIntent);
 }
```

```js
 private void initStartPlayer() {
   Constants.activityOff = false;
   //Broadcast from service
   LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Constants.mContext);
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction(Constants.serviceBroadcastIntent);
   bManager.registerReceiver(mServiceBroadcast, intentFilter);

   //Start Songs Helper Service
   Constants.mBackUpContentResolver = getContentResolver();

   setEnglishLang();

   mAnalytics = new AnalyticsHelper((AppumApplication) getApplication(),
     getString(R.string.app_analytics_id), getString(R.string.app_name));
   //Songs UI Helper
   mPlayerUiHelper = PlayerUiHelper.getInstance();

   tinydb = new TinyDB(Constants.mContext);
   tinydb.putBoolean("restart_service", false);
   utils = new Utilities();

   initUIfromService();
   Log.d(TAG, "Main Created");
 }
```

```js
 public void setViews() {

   Log.i(TAG, "Load Fragment Adapter");

   if (fragMngr == null)
     fragMngr = getSupportFragmentManager();

   if (mPager != null) {
     mPager.removeAllViews();
   }

   mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Constants.NUM_PAGES);
   mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fragMngr);
   mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
   mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomCircularViewPagerHandler());

   footer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.player_footer_bg);

   //Play lists spinner
   playListListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playListListView);
   listButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listButton);
   initPlayLists();

   albumCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.albumCover);
   songLabel = (ZenTextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
   albumName = (ZenTextView) findViewById(R.id.album_name);

   songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
   songCurrentDurationLabel = (ZenTextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
   songTotalDurationLabel = (ZenTextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
   bypass = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bypass);

   // All player buttons
   btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
   btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
   btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
   btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
   btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);

   prevButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
   prevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @
     Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
       mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
     }
   });
   nextButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
   nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @
     Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
       mPager.setCurrentItem(3);
     }
   });
 }
```

**This code - **SongsHelper.getInstance().startSongsScan()**; is scanning the songs in AsyncTask, it loads the ListView after the onPoastExcecute()

Please, Please! help me to get some rest :)

Answer (score 0):

In your initLists() method  call to setListAdapter();

Comment: This setListAdapter() is called after the songs list has been generated from the device.

initLists() is called before the songs list is being generated..

Answer (score 0):

you should create and set the adapter and the list on the main onResume() and after your AsyncTask is finished and the list is populated, call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and help!

I have finally found the solution.

Clear completely the adapters used by each fragment:

```
        try {
        mainFragment.songListAdapter.clear();
        mainFragment.songListAdapter = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    }
    try {
        albumSongListAdapter.clear();
        albumSongListAdapter = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    }
    try {
        artistSongListAdapter.clear();
        artistSongListAdapter = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    }
    try {
        albumGridAdapter.clear();
        albumGridAdapter = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    }
    try {
        artistGridAdapter.clear();
        artistGridAdapter = null;
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
    }
```

and than change this:

```
if (songsListView == null) {
    Log.d("Main Fragment", "initListView");
    songsListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.songsListView);
  }

  if (playListListView == null) {
    playListListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.playListListView);
    play_list_container = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_container);
  }
```

to this:

```
        songsListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.songsListView);            
        playListListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.playListListView);
        play_list_container = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_container);
```

Apparently it is a known bug when using listVies inside fragments inside ViewPager..